# Android Instagram ShareIntent Callback Method

Tags: android, instagram

I have started instagram intent to share an image on instagram

```
Intent instagram = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
instagram.setType("image/*");
instagram.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, mImageCaptureUri);
instagram.setPackage("com.instagram.android");
startActivityForResult(instagram, 7999);
```

but i want to be notified if the user shared the image or not

Like

```
 OnActivityResult();
```

Is there any way to get notified?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to get notified?

No. `ACTION_SEND` is not designed for use with `startActivityForResult()`. If you want to control this, use some Instagram SDK (if there is one) and upload the image yourself.

Comment: Instagram only allows to share content using their application we can not share using any other api or sdk.

https://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/media/#

As they said in documentation
At this time, uploading via the API is not possible. We made a conscious choice not to add this for the following reasons:

Comment: @farrukh: Then you will simply have to settle for not knowing if the user uploaded the image to Instagram or not.

Comment: Yes @CommonsWare you are right but i have an other way but that is not a good way thats why i have asked question if i got some better solution.

Comment: @farrukh can you explain the other way that you said you have to get notified if the content is shared?

Comment: @arash moeen you can get the content you shared on instagram you can compare with your post time stamp or some other content its just an idea you can make other logics to compare from getting recently shared contents.